# What unlocks the bonus levels in Slice It?

Tags: slice-it

In Slice It! (for Android, if that makes a difference), there is an extra "Bonus episode" with five levels, but no hints are supplied as to what unlocks them.

At some point I managed to unlock one of them, and I haven't finished the rest of the game, so apparently it's not a matter of "Complete all the levels and it will unlock".

So what do I need to do to open up those levels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Occasionally you will see a small present icon, that looks somewhat like the present in the world select menu for the "Bonus Levels".  If you click it, you will receive a message along the lines of "Congratulations! You may now play the bonus level!" and the associated bonus level will unlock.

For example, this is one on the game's "About" page (top-right corner):

[image: Screenshot of the game's About page]

I haven't kept track of exactly where they are, but aside from the above one (which unlocked Bonus #1 for me), I think some are inside levels and some are on the level select screen - IIRC one was on the second 'screen' of level selection in World 2.

As a side note, each present appears to be associated with a specific bonus level, because I had the second one unlocked for a long time before I realised this was the trigger.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of the level unlocks aren't related to simply completing levels, but are related to getting a certain number of total stars overall, so you want to make sure that you do well in each level, getting as close to 5 stars as you can.

If I recall correctly, you don't need to 5 star everything to unlock all of the levels.

Comment: Not sure if you play this a lot, but I discovered what I believe to be the actual answer, which you may find of interest if you do play the game...